# Validity of the Definiton of the Conditional

Tags: proof, fitch

Can a proof for

Premise (P→Q)
...
Goal (¬P∨Q)

be derived using only the following rules?
Conjunction Introduction
Conjunction Elimination Left
Conjunction Elimination Right
Disjunction Introduction Left
Disjunction Introduction Right
Disjunction Elimination
Conditional Introduction
Conditional Elimination
Negation Introduction
Falsum Introduction
Negation Elimination
Falsum Elimination

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3812067/prove-a-rightarrow-b-vdash-neg-a-vee-b-using-natural-deduction)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.   Indeed, it may be proven by using the rules: Conditional Elimination, Left Disjunction Introduction, Right Disjunction Elimination, Falsum Introduction, Negation Introduction, and Negation Elimination; although not in that order.   Also you will need to raise and discharge some assumptions along the way, as needed.